# Java EE updatetool with Python Decoding Error

Tags: java, python, ubuntu-14.04, java-ee-7

I am currently reading the JavaEE 7 Tutorial from Oracle. After installing the Glassfish 4 I am asked to update the tutorial samples using `updatetool` from the `bin` directory.

```
nowak@machine:~/Java/glassfish4/bin$ ./updatetool 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nowak/Java/glassfish4/updatetool/bin/../vendor-packages/updatetool/main.py", line 431, in ?
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/nowak/Java/glassfish4/updatetool/bin/../vendor-packages/updatetool/main.py", line 57, in main
    init_app_locale()
  File "/scratch/java_re/BUILD_AREA/workspace/updatecenter2.3-sustaining/uc2/build/dist/linux-i386/updatetool/vendor-packages/updatetool/common/boot.py", line 300, in init_app_locale
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 69: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am seeing other questions where the issue seems to be a missing 32bit library on a 64bit Ubuntu 14.04. Unfortunately, my error does not tell me, which lib is missing, as it does in the other questions.

How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "resolved" my problem by calling `updatetool` with a preceding `LANG=C` and installing a few other missing libraries.

```
LANG=C /dir-to-javaee-skd/bin/updatetool
```